# Calculation of probability.

Tags: probability

I have the following density function

$$ f(x,y) = \frac{21}{4}x^2y$$ for $x^2 \le y \le 1$

Calculate $P[Y \ge 3/4 | X= 1/2]=?$

---

My solution

$$P[Y \ge 3/4 | X= 1/2] = \frac {P[Y \ge 3/4, X= 1/2]}{P(X=1/2)}$$

I cannot further do that.

Comment: You need to use the conditional density $f_{Y|X}(y|1/2)=\frac{f(1/2,y)}{f_{X}(1/2)}:1/4 \leq y \leq 1$ to find this probability.

Comment: how? Can you please help me to do that? @MatthewH.

Comment: $P[X=2]=0$! The useful (but soppy) notation $E[Y\in A|X=x]$ means something other than $\frac{P[Y\in A,X=x]}{P[X=x]}$.

Comment: the number $P[Y \ge 3/4 | X= 1/2]$ doesn't exists. Or said more clearly: you can set it to be anything, as the event $\{X=1/2\}$ have zero measure

Comment: @Masacroso I have no further info. For example, I calculated $P(X \ge Y)$. and I found $P(X \ge Y)=0.3$ but I cannot find this given conditional probability.

Comment: @1190 I already said that you cannot compute this probability, as it doesn't have a fixed value

Comment: @Masacroso That's both true in a theoretical context and misleading in this particular context, which is arguably the worst type of answer to give someone who is already confused.  There is good reason to interpret this conditional probability via the conditional density, reflecting the amount of continuity $f$ exhibits.